# SublimeText3で、1つのショートカットにコマンドを2つ設定する方法が知りたい

Tags: sublimetext

SublimeText3において、ctrl+aを押下したら、「全て保存」+「Chromeのアクティブタブの再読込」をショートカットとして登録したいのですが、ショートカットで2つのコマンドを実行させる方法をご存知ないでしょうか？

・登録したいショートカット
ctrl+a

・登録したいコマンド
save_allとbrowser_refresh

※補足
browser_refreshはSublimeText3のプラグインの1つで、ctrl+shift+rを押下すると、「SublimeText3上のアクティブなファイルが上書き保存」され、「Chromeのアクティブタブの再読込」が実行されます。

例えば、HTMLとCSSファイルを1つずつ開いており、CSSファイルがアクティブな状況において、ctrl+shift+rを押下すると、CSSファイルのみが上書き保存され、Chromeのアクティブタブが再読込されます。

しかし、私はHTMLとCSSを同時に編集することが多いため、「アクティブなタブの上書き保存」という動作では、アクティブでないファイルの変更が保存されず、変更箇所が反映されないため、すべて保存を選択した上でctrl+shift+rという2つの動作を行わなくてはならず、これが不便に感じます。

――――――――――――――――――――

説明が少し長くなりましたが、特定のキーを押下したら、「全て保存」+「Chromeのアクティブタブの再読込」を実現できれば手段は問わない、という趣旨の質問です。

Answer (score 0):

ご質問の時間から考えてすでにご解決されている可能性もありますが、コメントさせていただきます。

ご要望を満たすためのアプローチがおそらく 3 つあるかと思います。

- a) 対象の複数コマンドを実行するマクロを登録して、 `run_macro_file` コマンドでそのマクロを呼び出すキーバインディングを登録する
- b) Chain of Command パッケージをインストールしてこれを利用する
- c) 自作のパッケージを作成して、対象の複数コマンドを実行するコマンドを作成する。そして、そのコマンドを実行するキーバインディングを登録する

本質的にはどのアプローチでも同じなので、 Masaki さんが好きな方法をお選びになるとよいかと思います。

以下参考リンクです。

- a) http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html
- b) https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command
- c) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646552/is-it-possible-to-chain-key-binding-commands-in-sublime-text-2

ご参考になれば幸いです。